# What is the % operator? Why is 4 % 3 = 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry this is a dumb question. I'm trying to relearn math:

$4 / 3 = 1.333....$

So, why is 4 % 3 = 1?

I have 4 cats. I cut them evenly into three groups, meaning each group contains 1.3333th of a cat. Why is 0.33333 not a remainder? I think I am overthinking this.

Comment: In programming, that symbol denotes $mod$.  Thus $4\%3=1$ means $4\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: Side question:  why would someone use "cats" as the object they are slicing up?

Comment: It's more typical to refer to this as 'mod' i.e. 4 mod 3 = 1. Suppose you had four cats and three friends: You wouldn't give a third of a cat to any of them.

Comment: think about remainders

Comment: remainder function(mod function more precisely).

Comment: @Semiclassical That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: But note:  % is not a standard math symbol.  It is a symbol in certain computer languages.

Comment: In what math curriculum are you seeing % ?  It's very uncommon outside of C style programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

The remainder $r=a\%b$ is such that $a=b \cdot q+r$.

Here, $r=0.333...$ is such that $a=b\cdot (q+r)$ and is not the remainder of the euclidean division (which is an integer). Indeed, $0.333...\cdot3=1=4\%3$.

(So "your" remainder is the "usual" remainder divided by $b$)

Answer (score 0):

The $\%$ operator is also known as the modulus or remainder operator.

It is the remainder of the integer-division of the dividend and divisor.

---

So if $ 4 / 3 = 1 + \frac{1}{3} $ (or $1$ with remainder $1$),

then

$ 4 \% 3 = 1 $.

---

Another example:

$ 30 / 7 = 4 + \frac{2}{7} $

so

$ 30 \% 7 = 2 $